# React Native Android APK hangs on a gray/white screen when opened then crashes after

Tags: android, react-native, crash, apk

I have a react native app, works fine on my android emulator, but when I build an apk(debug or release), it opens, hangs on a white/gray screen (depends on your splash screen props) and then crashes after a few seconds.

Side note, its not a splash screen issue.

I've tried removing the splash screen to see the behaviour, same thing.. added it back, same issue.